# Rescale axis ticks and text in d3.js multi y-axis plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, axis

I have a parallel coordinates plot that is based off this code: http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/2409451

I am trying to get the tick marks and the numbers on the y axes to scale from the min to the max of the data rather than autoscaling to the conveniently linear numbers like it currently done.

I have not been able to find any example of using d3 or js where a plot of any sort does this unless the data happens to land on those values.

I have been able to just show the min and max value, but cannot get ticks between these by replacing the 3rd line of //Add an axis and title with:

```
.each(function(d) {d3.select(this).call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y[d]).tickValues(y[d].domain()).orient("left")); })
```

For reference, the data file is read in as a .csv and ends up looking like this with alphabet representing the headings in the .csv file:

```
var example_data = [
                   {"a":5,"b":480,"c":250,"d":100,"e":220},
                   {"a":1,"b":90,"c":50,"d":33,"e":88}
];
```

**EDIT:**

The main issue is iterating over the array that has the domains for each column to create a new array with the tick values. Tick values can be set using:

```
d3.svg.axis().scale(y[d]).tickValues(value 1[d],value 2[d], etc)
```

y[d] is set by:

```
// Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
return d != "name" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
    .range([h, 0]));
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the min and the max you can map them in any way you want to any scale you want [y0,yn]. For example with y0 = 100, yn = 500 (because HTML counts from top and down).

Here I use a linear scale

```
d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([yourMin,yourMax])
    .range([y0,yn]);
```

Does this help?

Comment: I have no issue finding the proper min and max values from the dataset. It is the tick marks and tick values that are not scaling properly. When js creates these, it does so with round step sizes between the ticks of say 1,2,5,10, etc. I need to set the step size for each axis using the data (my dataset is always changing so the number of columns is not set). I cannot hard code the step sizes. I cannot figure out how to iterate over the array with the domain values to determine the step size for each column. You can set the tick sizes using d3.svg.axis().tickValues(value 1, value 2, etc).